# Cannot connect to X server error capybara-webkit in ubuntu

Tags: ruby, rubygems, web-scraping, capybara, capybara-webkit

Need help. Scripted in ruby (Not rails) and capybara-webkit gem used. Checked both on EC2 and Linode and this error persists.

`webkit_server: cannot connect to X server 
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/capybara-webkit-0.12.1/lib/capybara/driver/webkit/connection.rb:103:in attempt_connect'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/capybara-webkit-0.12.1/lib/capybara/driver/webkit/connection.rb:96:inconnect'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:62:in timeout'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/capybara-webkit-0.12.1/lib/capybara/driver/webkit/connection.rb:94:inconnect'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/capybara-webkit-0.12.1/lib/capybara/driver/webkit/connection.rb:17:in initialize'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/capybara-webkit-0.12.1/lib/capybara/driver/webkit.rb:26:innew'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/capybara-webkit-0.12.1/lib/capybara/driver/webkit.rb:26:in initialize'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/capybara-webkit-0.12.1/lib/capybara/webkit.rb:5:innew'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/capybara-webkit-0.12.1/lib/capybara/webkit.rb:5
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/capybara-1.1.2/lib/capybara/session.rb:61:in call'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/capybara-1.1.2/lib/capybara/session.rb:61:indriver'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/capybara-1.1.2/lib/capybara/session.rb:157:in visit'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/capybara-1.1.2/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:161:invisit'`

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the xvfb package to generate a virtual framebuffer.
Issue resolved https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/402